# Can I add object field to SPItem, to attach some kind of object to item?

Tags: sharepoint, moss, wss, field

I have an SPListItem object. Can I add a field to store some kind of object like ArrayList or Dictionary, or whatever?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SPListItem.Properties to store custom information which does not belong to a specific SPField. Dont forget to call Update()/SystemUpdate() after setting a property.